# Detect SDCard in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, sd-card

Need help with this SDCard code.I am using this piece of code
but its working accurate randomly.

```
boolean sdCardExist() {  
    boolean sdCardPresent = false;  

    Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();  
    while (e.hasMoreElements())  
    {  
        final String root = (String)e.nextElement();  

        //System.out.println("=================>root: " + root);  
        if(root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/"))  
        {  
            sdCardPresent = true;  
        } 
        else {

        }  
    }
    return sdCardPresent;
}
```

I am debugging this with 9860 device and there is a SDCard in it.

Comment: May be, I haven't seen this post.but my problem is some times i am getting system/ only as root, sometime store/ and SDCard/ . My question is why this code is not working properly. and changing the output randomly.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to the other question (the duplicate).